# Unable to redirect to a new route by Ajax call after post method in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am doing a search operation. I am passing 3 search parameters in the form, which makes an ajax call. I am getting the response from the ajax call, but I am unable to redirect it to the new route, with the search response data. When I try to redirect, I get the full HTML Response. Unable to figure out how to redirect it to the new page with the new search results.

I am using: Laravel 5.5 with Ajax

form.blade.php

```
  <form id="myform">
     <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
     <input type="text" name="locality" id="locality">
     <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
     <button id="search" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
```

the ajax call i am making in the form.blade.php

```
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#search').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/api/searchlisting') }}",
            method: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                type: jQuery('#type').val(),
                city: jQuery('#city').val(),
                locality: jQuery('#locality').val()                    
            }),
            success: function(result){
                jQuery('.alert').show();
                                    jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
                                    console.log(result);
            },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
        });
</script>
```

I have defined my route in api.php

```
Route::post('/searchlisting', 'SearchController@searchtypes');
```

In my SearchController i have defined the following:

```
public static function searchtypes(Request $request){
    $data = array(
        'city' => $request->city,
        'type' => $request->type,
        'locality' => $request->locality
    );

    $result = SearchModel::searchtypes($data);
    return view('alllistings', ['listing' => $result]);
```

In my SearchModel I have defined the following:

```
 public static function searchtypes($inp = []){
    $result = DB::table('tbl_types')
                ->where('city', $inp['city'])
                ->where('type', $inp['type'])
                ->where('locality', $inp['locality'])
                ->get();
    return $result;
}
```

alllistings.blade.php

```
<head>
<title>Get listing near you area</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum- 
scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-color.css" id="colors">

</head>

<body>
@include('common/header')

<div class="row">

            <!-- Listing Item -->
        @foreach($listing as $key=> $result)
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="listing-item-container list-layout">
                    <a href="/listings-single-page/{{$result->id}}" class="listing-item">

                        <!-- Image -->
                        <div class="listing-item-image">
                            <img src="{{$result->timgpath}}" alt="">
                            <span class="tag">{{$result->locality}}</span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <div class="listing-item-content">
                            <!-- <div class="listing-badge now-open">Now Open</div> -->

                            <div class="listing-item-inner">
                                <h3>{{$result->title}} <i class="verified-icon"></i></h3>
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="padding-right: 6px; font-size: 19px;"></i><span>{{$result->city}}</span>
                                <div class="star-rating">


                            <!-- <span class="like-icon"></span> -->


                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
            @endforeach

        </div>
 </body>
```

In the ajax response I get the full HTML with the desired values. But how do I redirect it to the new page with the search results.

Comment: I think you don't need to run the Ajax if you want to show the search result on another page. You can directly use post method in form action at where you want to show result

Comment: @jaimin... Can you show me an example code on how to do this?? I am able to save form using form action but unable to redirect it.

Comment: please check my below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the ajax and just replace form code with this :

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="{{ url('/api/searchlisting') }}">
     <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
     <input type="text" name="locality" id="locality">
     <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
     <button id="search" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
```

And add csrf token field as hidden field

Comment: this doesn't work. it is redirecting to /api/searchlisting. But the Barebones HTML is being returned, with no data being passed, and the CSS and JS are also missed. The parameters are not being passed from the form to the controller.

Comment: ok.. i m able to pass the data, but the css and js path are messed up right now.

Comment: Moreover, on refresh, it asks to resubmit the form. i also have to maintain all the scripts, css and images in api folder in public. While it works, its not very elegant i feel. would love to hear inputs to make the solution better.

Comment: Can you please share your alllistings.blade.php file

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code of alllistings.blade.php. Can you plz have a look.

Comment: I think code is right. But you are using the Ajax to submit the form or not? As now you don't need to use ajax for submit form.

Comment: No. I am not using ajax to submit the form.